# is JDK assert necessary to use?

Tags: unit-testing

I read a book says “it makes sense to use assert for testing internal code. For instance:

```
private String welcome(String name) {
  assert name!=null && !name.isEmpty() : "name must be specified";
  return "Hello, " + name;
}
```

”
then the book introduces unite test.I wonder is it necessary to use assert even having unite test?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test verifies the behaviour of a portion of code based on some state and the parameters you provide.

At runtime any possible value (of the correct type) could be passed to your method and this is why you perform an `assert` everytime. If you want you program to terminate execution if you receive an unsupported argument then `assert` can be useful for this.

You may also want to take a look at throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` as this specifically describes what went wrong.

Comment: I am confused by this logic. I mean if I know (or find out by unit test) some unsupported argument will pass in ,why not I just do some prevention like throw  IllegalArgumentException ?

Comment: You certainly can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` but that does not simply *prevent* someone from passing in an unsupported argument. That throws an exception which gives the calling code the chance to handle this scenario. A unit test is there to check that when an unsupported argument is passed in, then the method correctly raises the exception you are expecting rather than just falling over.

Comment: I use the exception to give the calling code the change to handle the scenario. I use unit test to prevent the exception falling over .So what's the JDK assert used for ?

Comment: I personally always use an Exception over `assert` and this question explains why: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137158/is-it-better-to-use-assert-or-illegalargumentexception-for-required-method-param

Comment: @ Alex thank you.I read all your reference and understand some concept about assertions. But the only problem is that there aren't many practical example to demonstrate usage, give me some link if you have 。